# Very slow / No rotation of front wheels for an ackermann steering type model

Tags: gazebo, mobile-robot, wheeled-robot, steering, gazebo-ros2-control

I am trying to simulate a mobile robot with ackermann steering in Gazebo. I have velocity control for rear wheels and steering angle control for front wheels.
I am using ROS2 Humble with Gazebo.

There are total 6 continuous revolute joints (Note: Revolute joint here refers to general revolute joint, not the revolute joint specific to ROS). Out of 6 joints, 2 joints are between rear wheels and base link and their velocity is controlled. 2 joints are between base link and steering link and their position is controlled. Remaining two joints are free to rotate.

**Problem** -When I give the velocity command from /cmd_vel to /ackermann_steering_controller. The robot achieves the desired velocity, which indicates the /ackermann_steering_controller is working but the front wheels do not rotate much during this movement and they slip all the way. Because of which the steering is not achieved even when steering angle is correct, because there is no traction on front wheels.

I have put same friction coefficients for all the wheels.

- I have tried increasing the friction coefficients of front wheels.
- I have tried increasing the mass of front wheels.

Both of these caused my rear wheel to try push the robot but lose traction, since front wheels are stiff.

Any help will be appreciated.

These are my URDF files. I made the model in Fusion360 and exported to ROS2 using a plugin.

**roscar.gazebo**

```
    <xacro:property name="body_color" value="Gazebo/Silver" />

    <gazebo reference="base_link">
      <material>${body_color}</material>
      <mu1>0.2</mu1>
      <mu2>0.2</mu2>
      <self_collide>true</self_collide>
      <gravity>true</gravity>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="rear_right_1">
      <material>${body_color}</material>
      <self_collide>true</self_collide>
      <gravity>true</gravity>
      <mu1>20.0</mu1>
      <mu2>10.0</mu2>
      <minDepth>0.00</minDepth>
      <kp>1e15</kp>
      <kd>1e13</kd>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="rear_left_1">
      <material>${body_color}</material>
      <self_collide>true</self_collide>
      <gravity>true</gravity>
      <mu1>20.0</mu1>
      <mu2>10.0</mu2>
      <minDepth>0.00</minDepth>
      <kp>1e15</kp>
      <kd>1e13</kd>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="left_link_1">
      <material>${body_color}</material>
      <mu1>0.02</mu1>
      <mu2>0.02</mu2>
      <self_collide>true</self_collide>
      <gravity>true</gravity>
      
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="right_link_1">
      <material>${body_color}</material>
      <mu1>0.02</mu1>
      <mu2>0.02</mu2>
      <self_collide>true</self_collide>
      <gravity>true</gravity>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="front_right_1">
      <material>${body_color}</material>
      <self_collide>true</self_collide>
      <gravity>true</gravity>
      <mu1>20.0</mu1>
      <mu2>10.0</mu2>
      <minDepth>0.00</minDepth>
      <kp>1e15</kp>
      <kd>1e13</kd>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="front_left_1">
      <material>${body_color}</material>
      <self_collide>true</self_collide>
      <gravity>true</gravity>
      <mu1>20.0</mu1>
      <mu2>10.0</mu2>
      <minDepth>0.00</minDepth>
      <kp>1e15</kp>
      <kd>1e13</kd>
    
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="laser_frame">
            <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
     
            <sensor name="laser" type="ray">
                <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
                <visualize>false</visualize>
                <update_rate>10</update_rate>
                <ray>
                    <scan>
                        <horizontal>
                            <samples>100</samples>
                            <min_angle>-1.05</min_angle>
                            <max_angle>1.05</max_angle>
                        </horizontal>
                    </scan>
                    <range>
                        <min>0.01</min>
                        <max>1</max>
                    </range>
                </ray>
                <plugin name="laser_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
                    <ros>
                        <argument>~/out:=scan</argument>
                    </ros>
                    <output_type>sensor_msgs/LaserScan</output_type>
                    <frame_name>laser_frame</frame_name>
                </plugin>
            </sensor>
        </gazebo>
        
        <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
          <parameters>$(find roscar_description)/config/ackermann_param.yaml</parameters>
          <robotNamespace>/roscar</robotNamespace>
        </plugin>
      </gazebo>
    
    
    </robot>
```

**roscar.xacro**

```
    <xacro:include filename="$(find roscar_description)/urdf/materials.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="$(find roscar_description)/urdf/roscar.trans" />
    <xacro:include filename="$(find roscar_description)/urdf/roscar.gazebo" />
    
    <!--<link name="dummy">
    </link>-->
       
    <link name="base_link">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="-0.008093082114432633 7.024584393331645e-18 0.01456271093202775" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <mass value="0.5"/>
        <inertia ixx="4.9e-05" iyy="0.000175" izz="0.000209" ixy="-0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="7e-06"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/base_link.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="silver"/>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/base_link.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    
    <link name="rear_right_1">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="-7.476658181460039e-15 0.0049999999999999975 -3.469446951953614e-18" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <mass value="0.006391177554646729"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.0" iyy="1e-06" izz="0.0" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="-0.0"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0.03 0.035 -0.015" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/rear_right_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="silver"/>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0.03 0.035 -0.015" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/rear_right_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    
    <link name="rear_left_1">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="7.462780393652224e-15 -0.0049999999999999975 -3.469446951953614e-18" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <mass value="0.006391177554646729"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.0" iyy="1e-06" izz="0.0" ixy="-0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="-0.0"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0.03 -0.035 -0.015" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/rear_left_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="silver"/>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0.03 -0.035 -0.015" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/rear_left_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    
    <link name="left_link_1">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="-0.0015882948432884708 0.0001329791850876033 -0.0037007088076549" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <mass value="0.002800252290415452"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.0" iyy="0.0" izz="0.0" ixy="-0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="0.0"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="-0.0705 -0.0205 -0.019" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/left_link_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="silver"/>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="-0.0705 -0.0205 -0.019" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/left_link_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    
    <link name="right_link_1">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="-0.0015882948434864513 -0.0001329791850876033 -0.0037007088076549" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <mass value="0.002800252290415452"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.0" iyy="0.0" izz="0.0" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="0.0"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="-0.0705 0.0205 -0.019" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/right_link_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="silver"/>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="-0.0705 0.0205 -0.019" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/right_link_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    
    <link name="front_right_1">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="7.466249840604178e-15 0.0049999999999999975 8.673617379884035e-18" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <mass value="0.01"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.0" iyy="1e-06" izz="0.0" ixy="-0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="-0.0"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="-0.07 0.035 -0.015" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/front_right_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="silver"/>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="-0.07 0.035 -0.015" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/front_right_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    
    <link name="front_left_1">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="-7.466249840604178e-15 -0.0049999999999999975 8.673617379884035e-18" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <mass value="0.01"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.0" iyy="1e-06" izz="0.0" ixy="0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="-0.0"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="-0.07 -0.035 -0.015" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/front_left_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="silver"/>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="-0.07 -0.035 -0.015" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find roscar_description)/meshes/front_left_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    
    <joint name="Revolute1" type="continuous">
      <origin xyz="-0.03 -0.035 0.015" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="rear_right_1"/>
      <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 0.0"/>
      <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="Revolute2" type="continuous">
      <origin xyz="-0.03 0.035 0.015" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="rear_left_1"/>
      <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 0.0"/>
      <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="Revolute10" type="continuous">
      <origin xyz="0.0705 0.0205 0.019" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="left_link_1"/>
      <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
      <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="Revolute11" type="continuous">
      <origin xyz="0.0705 -0.0205 0.019" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="right_link_1"/>
      <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
      <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="Revolute12" type="continuous">
      <origin xyz="-0.0005 -0.0145 -0.004" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="right_link_1"/>
      <child link="front_right_1"/>
      <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 0.0"/>
      <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="Revolute13" type="continuous">
      <origin xyz="-0.0005 0.0145 -0.004" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="left_link_1"/>
      <child link="front_left_1"/>
      <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 0.0"/>
      <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
      <!--<joint name="dummy_joint" type="fixed">
         <parent link="dummy"/>
         <child link="base_link"/>
       </joint>-->
    
    
        <joint name="laser_joint" type="fixed">
            <parent link="base_link"/>
            <child link="laser_frame"/>
            <origin xyz="-0.03 0 0.033" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </joint>
     
        <link name="laser_frame">
            <visual>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder radius="0.007" length="0.008"/>
                </geometry>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder radius="0.007" length="0.008"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
    
        </link>
        
        <link name="imu">
        <inertial>
          <mass value="0.1"/>
          <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0" izz="1.0"/>
        </inertial>
      </link>
      <joint name="cart_to_imu" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="imu"/>
      </joint>
    
      <gazebo reference="imu">
        <sensor name="cart_imu_sensor" type="imu">
          <always_on>1</always_on>
          <update_rate>10.0</update_rate>
        </sensor>
      </gazebo>
      
      
        
        <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
          <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
        </hardware>
        
        <joint name="Revolute1">
          <command_interface name="velocity">
            <param name="min">-10</param>
            <param name="max">10</param>
          </command_interface>
          <state_interface name="position"/>
          <state_interface name="velocity"/>
          <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
        
        <joint name="Revolute2">
          <command_interface name="velocity">
            <param name="min">-10</param>
            <param name="max">10</param>
          </command_interface>
          <state_interface name="position"/>
          <state_interface name="velocity"/>
          <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
            
        <joint name="Revolute10">
          <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-10</param>
            <param name="max">10</param>
          </command_interface>
          <state_interface name="position"/>
          <state_interface name="velocity"/>
          <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
            
        <joint name="Revolute11">
          <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-10</param>
            <param name="max">10</param>
          </command_interface>
          <state_interface name="position"/>
          <state_interface name="velocity"/>
          <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="Revolute12">
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="Revolute13">
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
        
        <sensor name="cart_imu_sensor">
          <state_interface name="orientation.x"/>
          <state_interface name="orientation.y"/>
          <state_interface name="orientation.z"/>
          <state_interface name="orientation.w"/>
          <state_interface name="angular_velocity.x"/>
          <state_interface name="angular_velocity.y"/>
          <state_interface name="angular_velocity.z"/>
          <state_interface name="linear_acceleration.x"/>
          <state_interface name="linear_acceleration.y"/>
          <state_interface name="linear_acceleration.z"/>
        </sensor>
        
        
      </ros2_control>
      
    
        
    </robot>
```

**roscar.trans**

```
    <transmission name="Revolute1_tran">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="Revolute1">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="Revolute1_actr">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
    </transmission>
    
    <transmission name="Revolute2_tran">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="Revolute2">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="Revolute2_actr">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
    </transmission>
    
    <transmission name="Revolute10_tran">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="Revolute10">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="Revolute10_actr">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
    </transmission>
    
    <transmission name="Revolute11_tran">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="Revolute11">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="Revolute11_actr">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
    </transmission>
    
    <transmission name="Revolute12_tran">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="Revolute12">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="Revolute12_actr">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
    </transmission>
    
    <transmission name="Revolute13_tran">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="Revolute13">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="Revolute13_actr">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
    </transmission>
    
    </robot>
```

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Spiff. Where did you get your values for mass, inertia, and coefficient of friction? When I look [online at coefficients of friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Approximate_coefficients_of_friction), I see concrete and rubber is 1.0. Your config file is giving coefficients of friction 20 times more than that. Your chassis (base_link) weighs 500 grams, but the wheels each weigh 6 grams. Posts I find online about RC hobby vehicles give a total system weight (including wheels) at 500 g but wheels weighing 25-60 grams (~25% of chassis weight).

Comment: Those are the values I modified to get the simulation working properly. I increased the coefficient of friction and mass of the chassis trying to force rotation of the wheels.